# Which Machine Learning algorithm should I use for gender tagging of words in NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, natural-language

I have a dataset of about 26,000 words along with their gender tags [m, f or any]. 
Which ML algorithm should I use for Gender Tagging/Classification purpose. How should I go about it? What should be the input features?

Given a word , it's POS tags and in some cases the singularity I am trying to predict the gender of the word.

Comment: what are you trying to predict?

Comment: @redress Given a word , it's POS tags and in some cases the singularity I am trying to predict the gender of the word.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/283907/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76436/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one-hot encoding to map the gender of the word as follows:

male --> `[1, 0, 0]`

female --> `[0, 1, 0]`

other --> `[0, 0, 1]`

This tells your logistic regression that the input maps to 100% of that class of the output.  Once you train your logistic regression algorithm, your predictions will be of the following form after passing through the final [Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function:

`[0.1, 0.9, 0.1]`

Indicating that the word is female with 90% probability.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with domain knowledge.  What do you know about what patterns might be present in the language that a human might use to form a guess about the gender of a particular word?

For instance, Spanish has [some simple rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Spanish/Gender_of_nouns): words that end in 'o' are often masculine, and words that end in 'a' are often feminine.  But not always; there are exceptions.  So, in Spanish, a good feature to use would be the last letter of the word.  You could also try using the last two letters as a feature.

As you can see, this is likely to be language-specific.  You could try to do something language-independent, but I expect that language-specific features that take into account some domain knowledge about the language will enable your ML algorithm to perform a lot better.